# Реакция на ответ боту в чате telegram aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Нужно сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял сообщение в чате только тогда, когда человек написал определенное слово именно ответом на другое определенное сообщение бота.
Помогите реализовать

```
@dp.message_handler() 
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):    
    if "Мат" in message.text.lower():   
        await message.reply('Веди себя прилично, приблуда!')
```

Comment: Покажите что у вас уже есть. Минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: `@dp.message_handler() async def filter_messages(message: types.Message): 
 if "Мат" in message.text.lower(): 
 wait message.reply('Веди себя прилично, приблуда!')`

Comment: Нужно сделать, например так: Бот сообщением пишет "я вернулся", человек делает ответ на это сообщение - "откуда". И только тогда бот уже ответит "Ото сна". Триггер только на эти фразы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужно посмотреть про машину состояний.

Код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

class StateGroupExample(StatesGroup):
    wait_for_answer = State() #создаёте состояние
```

```
from main import bot, dp, asyncio
from aiogram import types
from states import FSMContext, StateGroupExample

@dp.message_handler()
async def help(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(text='я вернулся')
    await StateGroupExample.wait_for_answer.set() #теперь бот будет ловить сообщения в хендлеры с установленным состоянием

@dp.message_handler(state=StateGroupExample.wait_for_answer, text=['откуда'])
async def help(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == 'откуда':
        await message.answer(text='Ото сна')
    await state.finish()
```

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from config import BOT_TOKEN
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, loop=loop, storage=MemoryStorage())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from handlers import dp
    executor.start_polling(dp) #передаём диспатчер со стораджем
```

Comment: Появилась ошибка <from states import FSMContext, StateGroupExample
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'states'>. Я созовем новичок в этом деле, так что извиняюсь, если буду задавать глупые вопросы. Весь остальной код у меня в одном файле

Comment: @zemka ваш импорт не видит файл states. Это может быть связано с тем, что вы назвали его по-другому либо он находится выше/ниже в каталоге. 
Вы ведь создали этот файл и положили туда код с созданием состояния да?

Comment: Я хотел сделать все в одном файле, для начала. Сейчас сделал все так, но появилась новая ошибка :ImportError: cannot import name 'FSMContext' from 'states' (C:\Bott\states.py)

Comment: @zemka Добавил в код все необходимые импорты. Теперь ваш бот запустится 